# how to get select value with input values in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Can any one help how to get input and selected values by dynamically added with **angularjs**?

**Here is my code in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NOqQdj0f86SMvOeQqj0V?p=preview)**

When I select vegtables, another input shows with some values. when I click submit button I need a json like

```
{
"itemName":"Mango",
"itemType":"fruits"
},
{
"itemName":"Carrot",
"itemType":"vegtables",
"iteminfo":"you selected Carrot"
},
{
"itemName":"Apple",
"itemType":"fruits"
}
```

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question. Please explain.

Comment: your question and code doesn't really make sense.  It *feels* like what you want is to be able to filter the items, but that isn't the case.  right now, if you selected `vegetables` next to the `Mango` dropdown, it would show "You selected Mango`, which I doubt is your end goal.  Even the answers produce the same result.  You should consider providing a bit more information about what the relationship should be between these select boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I forked your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/giTjTic28SWfvrLCwPbk?p=preview)

You can bind itemInfo to an item object using ng-model.  Rather than placing the text in a value attribute I just initialized the model value using ng-init.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="item in Items">
    <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.itemName">
    </td>

    <td>
      <select ng-model="item.itemType">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option vaue="fruits">Fruits</option>
        <option value="vegtables">Vegtables</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div ng-switch on="item.itemType">
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.itemInfo" ng-switch-when="vegtables" ng-init="item.itemInfo='you selected '+ item.itemName">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Also I had to change the Items array to match your requested naming:

```
  $scope.Items = [{itemName: "Mango"}, {itemName: "Carrot"}, {itemName: "Apple"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON object in a for loop to get the selected value and add the new key value pair.

`angular.forEach($scope.vegetables, function(value, key){
         if(value.itemName== 'Carrot')
           value.iteminfo = 'you selected Carrot';
         });`

I  guess you might be looking for something like this, if I am not wrong.